How to IP restrict App Services while still allowing Vercel to access them
I'm working on a Sitecore implementation built on Sitecore Managed Cloud (PaaS 1.0). The head application is hosted on Vercel. In Azure, we have CM and CD App Services. I want to IP restrict my App Services, but there doesn't appear to be an out of the box way to allow Vercel to access them because Vercel does not provide any IP ranges that I can add to an allow list.
Vercel's documentation states:

Currently, you need to allow all IP addresses on your backend cloud for your Vercel deployment to be able to connect to it. For security and compliance reasons, you may not be permitted to publicly expose your backend cloud. Even if authentication is required, exposing data sources to the world can be unsafe.

Based on this, it seems that implementations built with Vercel are not fully secure, given that the App Services must be accessible to the public.
There is a solution provided by Vercel (as of May 2023), but it requires an Enterprise plan and is an add on. The solution is "Secure Compute":

By enabling Secure Compute on your Project, your deployments and build container will be placed in a private network with dedicated IP addresses in a region of your choice and logically separated from other containers.

In my specific case, the cost for the Secure Compute add on is too expensive at this time. Are there any other creative solutions?

You can go with Azure app service where you can add IP restrictions

@AmitKumar as in, use Azure App Services to host the head app instead of Vercel?

Yes, deployment on Azure

Agree with @AmitKumar.  You can password protect your Vercel preview sites as long as Vercel is only serving in a rendering host role and not pulling double duty as rendering & editing host.      Azure can provide private editing host app services for solving this problem.
